# How to initiate refresh of Vuejs page elements w/ new data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vuejs app using vue-router with the following routes.

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/list', component: list, alias: '/' },
  { path: '/resources/:id?', component: resources },
  { path: '/emails', component: emails },
  { path: '/list/:id', component: editHousehold, props: true },
  { path: '/list/turn-off/:id', component: editHousehold, props: true }
]
```

The first time the page loads the start event calls /resources w/o an ":id" and the page loads a list of resources (see below).

```
start: function () {
  this.$http.get('/resources')
    .then((res) => {
      let gdriveInfo = res.data;
      this.files = gdriveInfo.files;
    }
    );
},
```

Resource1

Resource2

Rescouce3

...

When the user clicks on one of the resources in the list I want to have /resources/1 called so a different set of resource data can be loaded and displayed.

I have a file click event attached to each resource where the "id" is appended to the path. This calls the server side module which would retrieve new data which would replace the "files" data in the component which I would expect would cause vuejs to "react" and update the contents of the page.

```
onFileClick: function (id, mimeType, event) {
  const _this = this;
  this.$http.get('/resources/' + id)
    .then((res) => {
      let gdriveInfo = res.data;
      this.files = gdriveInfo.files;
    }
    );
}
```

However, calling above does not initiate a call to the server module.

```
this.$http.get('/resources/' + id)
```

I've also tried

```
this.$router.push('/resources/' + id)
```

which did not work.

Being new to vuejs, any help in how to achieve this functionality would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, the onFileClick event is called but this.$http.get('/resources/' + id) does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You lack host, because this.$http.get('/resources/' + id) is u component resources, this not json...

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "host". Why doesn't this.$router.get('/resouces/' + id) initiate a call to the server whenever it is executed?

Comment: Sorry, i not see u start function,this.$http.get('/resources') direction isn't u router, you component resources return is json?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not making the REST call correctly. I think you're getting routing and REST calls mixed up. What you show above is for routing not making calls to the server.

You're not calling the server here:
`this.$http.get('/resources/' + id)`

and doing this is just for the routing:
`this.$router.push('/resources/' + id)`

Look at using axios for REST calls:
https://github.com/axios/axios